# android support all screen sizes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-screen-support

I try to create my app that will look the same on every screen size.
I added the next layout folder:
[image]

and still when I connected the Galaxy s5 phone I see different from what I design.
thanks for your help!

Comment: Issue solved ???

Answer (score 0):

Read official guideline about [**`Support different screen sizes`**](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes)

> Android devices come in all shapes and sizes, so your app's layout
>   needs to be flexible. That is, instead of defining your layout with
>   rigid dimensions that assume a certain screen size and aspect ratio,
>   your layout should gracefully respond to different screen sizes and
>   orientations.

Specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable screen compatibility mode for screens larger than what your application supports. It's important that you always use this element in your application to specify the screen sizes your application supports.

```
 <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

For **`Responsive`** Textsize issue, You can use [**`SDP - a scalable size unit`**](https://github.com/intuit/sdp). This size unit scales with the screen size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.